# javascript multiple parentheses function call

Tags: javascript, recursion, closures

I'm trying to solve some javascript puzzle. I have some function (for example a function which calculates summa).
But there is a weird calling of that function.
example:

sum(5)

or sum(5,6) - should be 11

or sum(5)(6) - should be 11

or sum(1)(2)(3) - should be 6

Have never seen such function calling **sum(1)(2)(3)(4)**....
Can you please explain or maybe put into documentation where this stuff is explained?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If the `sum` function returns a function, that function can also be invoked.

Comment: Does the **accepted answer** answer your question? [What is 'Currying'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying)

Comment: I've tried return function inside function, but it works only with sum(1) and sum(2,3), but not with sum(2)(3) and more :(

Answer (score 0):

If the sum function returns a value that it can reuse, you can chain the numbers on and on.

If you can share the function it can be easier to explain